# Unhandled Exception: type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I want to revise this title error.

Could you have any ideas for solving.

main.dart

```
Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                        child: Text(workout.reportList,
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
                      ),
```

main_model.dart

```
List<String> reportList = [
    "Not relevant",
    "Illegal",
    "Spam",
    "Offensive",
    "Uncivil"
  ];

Future add(model) async {
    final collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('workoutlist');
    await collection.add({
      'title': newWorkoutText,
      'count': int.parse(newWorkoutDigit),
      "category": reportList,
      'createdAt': Timestamp.now(),
    });
```

add_page.dart

```
List<String> reportList;
List<String> selectedChoices = List();

Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: ChoiceChip(
                    label: Text(model.reportList.toString()),
                    selected: isSelected,
                    selectedColor: Colors.teal,
                    onSelected: (selected) {
                      setState (() {
                        isSelected = selected;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
```

workout.dart

```
  Workout(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    this.documentReference = doc.reference;
    this.reportList = doc.data()['category'].toString();
  }

  String reportList;
  bool isDone = false;
```

[image]

I want to separate these components but now this List is collected

Comment: Check type of value int `Text` widget.

Comment: I changed "String reportList" -> "List<String> reportList"

Comment: And the error is now '' type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' ''

Comment: int is not concern with List.
Why do you say like that?

Comment: on which file do u get this error?

Answer (score 0):

`reportList` is not a `String`, it is a `List`. If you pass a value to `Text` widget, a value must be `String`.

Comment: I got another error "Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'"

Comment: Can you show collection value from Firestore?